# how to get all span data attribute inside p element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all the `span` data attribute inside the `p` element so that I can compare the values/text of my hidden `p` element

```
<div>   
    <ol class="edit-list">
       <li class="edit">
         <p  class="hidden answer" data-answer="He loves fish tacos">He loves fish tacos</p>
         <p>
            <span data-original="Brad">He</span>
            <span data-original="loves">loves</span>
            <span data-original="fish">fish</span>
            <span data-original="tactos">tactos</span>                       
         </p>               
       </li>

       <li class="edit">
         <p  class="hidden answer" data-answer="I love learning!">I love learning!</p>
         <p>
           <span data-original="I">I</span>
           <span data-original="love">love</span>
           <span data-original="learning!">learning!</span>
         </p>
       </li>
       <li class="edit">
          <p  class="hidden answer" data-answer="I ate dinner">I ate dinner</p>
          <p>
             <span data-original="I">I</span>
             <span data-original="ate">ate</span>
             <span data-original="dinner">dinner</span>
           </p>
         </li>
      </ol>
      <button id="validate" >Validate</button>
 </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
        var mismatch = false;
        $('ol.edit-list li').each(function(){
            var p_answer =  $(this).find('p').attr('data-answer');
            
            var c_annswer =  $(this).find('p').has('span').children().attr('data-original'); // I canno get all the span inside the p;
            
              if(p_answer !== c_answer){
                 mismatch = true;
                 break;
              }
          }         
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).find('p').has('span').children()` loop over this.

Comment: Your code crashes and the console says `Illegal break statement`. You can't use `break` in a `.forEach` loop (but you can in a `for` loop or a `switch` statement)

Comment: @evolutionxbox how can I concat ? so that it will form to 1 sentence

Comment: Consider using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: @jemz Well, open your console, it's telling you this. The console is _very_ useful :)

Comment: `.has('span').children();` selects all the `<span>`. Now you have to iterate over each of them and extract their `.attr('data-original')` (or shorthand `.data('original')`).

Comment: @JeremyThille should I use return false  insead break; ?

Comment: Dunno, try it, does the console complain?

Comment: Ok return false is correct console did not complaint, thanks :)